# SettingWithCopyWarning. ¿Por qué usando .iloc nos devuelve este error y usando .loc no?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter

La advertencia SettingWithCopy sale cuando hay un indexado encadenado ya que este puede generar resultados inesperados ([documentación oficial](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) ). La sugerencia para corregirlo es utilizar .loc o .iloc.

¿Por qué en este ejemplo que adjunto a continuación, con .iloc me devuelve este error y con .loc no?.

DataFrame:

```
from datetime import datetime       
import pandas as pd

Date = ['2018-02-06 ' , '2018-06-29 ', '2019-07-09 ', '2020-03-16 ', '2020-08-24',  '2020-12-03',  '2020-12-15','2021-01-08 ' , '2021-01-27 ','2021-04-16 ']
Close = [150.61, 160.08, 178.17, 140.35, 189.4, 200.6, 202.46, 209.26, 207.54, 230.39] 
Position = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1 ]

data = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(Date, Close, Position)), columns =['Date', 'Close', 'Position']) 

data['Date'] = data['Date'].astype('datetime64') 
data.set_index('Date', inplace = True)
```

Opción con .iloc.

```
df = data.copy(deep=True)

df['Buy/Sell'] = 0

for i in range (1, len(df)):
    if (df['Position'].iloc[i] == 1) and (df['Position'].iloc[i-1] == 1): # hold the position
        df.loc[i, 'Buy/Sell']  = 'Hold'

    if (df['Position'].iloc[i] == 0) and (df['Position'].iloc[i-1]) == 0: # hold the position
        df['Buy/Sell'].iloc[i]  = 'Hold'
        
    if (df['Position'].iloc[i] == 1) and (df['Position'].iloc[i-1] == 0):    # sell
        df['Buy/Sell'].iloc[i]  = 'Buy'
                                          
    if (df[ 'Position'].iloc[i] == 0) and (df['Position'].iloc[i-1] == 1):   # buy
        df['Buy/Sell'].iloc[i]  = 'Sell'

df[df['Buy/Sell'] != 'Hold'].dropna()
```

Devuelve:

```
home/enri/anaconda3/envs/yfinance1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:1732: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  self._setitem_single_block(indexer, value, name)
```

[image: imágen con iloc.]
Opción loc.

```
df = data.reset_index()

for i in range (1, len(df)):
    if (df.loc[i, 'Position'] == 1) and (df.loc[i-1, 'Position'] == 1): # hold the position
        df.loc[i, 'Buy/Sell']  = 'Hold'

    if (df.loc[i, 'Position'] == 0) and (df.loc[i-1, 'Position']) == 0: # hold the position
        df.loc[i, 'Buy/Sell']  = 'Hold'
        
    if (df.loc[i, 'Position'] == 1) and (df.loc[i-1, 'Position'] == 0):    # sell
        df.loc[i, 'Buy/Sell']  = 'Buy'
                                          
    if (df.loc[i, 'Position'] == 0) and (df.loc[i-1, 'Position'] == 1):   # buy
        df.loc[i, 'Buy/Sell']  = 'Sell'

df[df['Buy/Sell'] != 'Hold'].dropna()
```

Devuelve:

[image: Devolución con .loc]

Agradeceré todas las aclaraciones que me faciliten la compresión de la causa por la que se manifiesta este error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buen día,

En primer lugar, lo que estás haciendo con `iloc` y `loc` no es equivalente y por eso con `iloc` te aparecen esas alarmas. En tu código estás haciendo `iloc` de una serie y no del `dataframe` como lo haces con `loc` pero de igual forma estás iterando en los índices cuando utilizas `iloc` y cuando utilizas `loc` creas un nuevo índice e iteras sobre este, por lo que los códigos no son equivalentes.

Para utilizar `iloc` en el `dataframe` y no en la serie como tu lo muestras en la pregunta tendrías que hacerlo de la siguiente forma (Las columnas tienen valor numérico empezando por `0`):

```
df = data.copy(deep=True)

df['Buy/Sell'] = 0

for i in range (1, len(df)):
    if (df.iloc[i,1] == 1) and (df.iloc[i-1,1] == 1): # hold the position
        df.iloc[i, 2]  = 'Hold'

    if (df.iloc[i,1] == 0) and (df.iloc[i-1,1] == 0): # hold the position
        df.iloc[i, 2]  = 'Hold'
        
    if (df.iloc[i,1] == 1) and (df.iloc[i-1,1] == 0):    # sell
        df.iloc[i, 2]  = 'Buy'
                                          
    if (df.iloc[i,1] == 0) and (df.iloc[i-1,1] == 1):   # buy
        df.iloc[i, 2]  = 'Sell'

df[df['Buy/Sell'] != 'Hold'].dropna()
```

Para hacer lo mismo pero utilizando `loc` primero debes utilizar el mismo índice que ya tiene el `dataframe`, no crear uno nuevo y tendrías que acceder a su valor numérico de una forma muy fea (Tan fea como utilizar `for` con `pandas`, broma):

```
df = data.copy(deep=True)

df['Buy/Sell'] = 0

for i in range (1, len(df)):
    if (df.loc[df.index[i], 'Position'] == 1) and (df.loc[df.index[i-1], 'Position'] == 1): # hold the position
        df.loc[df.index[i], 'Buy/Sell']  = 'Hold'

    if (df.loc[df.index[i], 'Position'] == 0) and (df.loc[df.index[i-1], 'Position']) == 0: # hold the position
        df.loc[df.index[i], 'Buy/Sell']  = 'Hold'
        
    if (df.loc[df.index[i], 'Position'] == 1) and (df.loc[df.index[i-1], 'Position'] == 0):    # sell
        df.loc[df.index[i], 'Buy/Sell']  = 'Buy'
                                          
    if (df.loc[df.index[i], 'Position'] == 0) and (df.loc[df.index[i-1], 'Position'] == 1):   # buy
        df.loc[df.index[i], 'Buy/Sell']  = 'Sell'

df[df['Buy/Sell'] != 'Hold'].dropna()
```

Ahora los códigos son equivalentes y ninguno de los dos muestra alarmas.

La razón por la que te mostraba tantas alarmas en la parte de `iloc` es porque en primer lugar, tienes un `loc` en la primera condición, en segundo lugar, por lo que entiendo de la documentación, cuando haces `df['AlgunaColumna']` esto crea una copia/slice y al encadenar `.iloc` entonces se crea el problema. Por lo que deberías utilizar `iloc` directamente en el `dataframe` como en el primer ejemplo.

De igual forma no sería la forma óptima de hacerlo.

**Nota:** Al utilizar `pandas` es recomendable no utilizar ciclos (Por ejemplo `for`) para iterar en los elementos, hay métodos optimizados que trabajan con el `dataset` rápida y eficientemente. En la mayoría de los casos, si lo que quieres hacer crees que se puede hacer con un `for` entonces es el camino INCORRECTO (O el que va a tardar más y tener mayor impacto al procesador). En esos casos, si no hay un método directo que realice la tarea entonces apply podría ser una buena opción, como último recurso sería utilizar ciclos.

Como en este caso debes tomar en cuenta el valor de una columna y el valor de la fila anterior de esa misma columna entonces puedes utilizar [`pandas.Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) para crear una nueva columna temporal con el valor anterior, luego hacer una función y aplicarla al `dataframe` con [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

Ejemplo completo:

```
# Función que define el tipo de movimiento a realizar
def movement(row):
    if ((row['Position'] == 1) and (row['Position - 1'] == 1)) or ((row['Position'] == 0) and (row['Position - 1'] == 0)):
        row['Buy/Sell'] = 'Hold'
    elif (row['Position'] == 1) and (row['Position - 1'] == 0):
        row['Buy/Sell'] = 'Buy'
    elif (row['Position'] == 0) and (row['Position - 1'] == 1):
        row['Buy/Sell'] = 'Sell'
    return row

df = data.copy(deep=True)

# Creamos la columna temporal con el valor anterior de Position
df['Position - 1'] = df['Position'].shift(1)

# Inicializamos Buy/Sell
df['Buy/Sell'] = 0

# Aplicamos la función movement y eliminamos la columna temporal "Position - 1"
df = df.apply(movement, axis=1).drop(columns = ['Position - 1'])

# Dataframe resultante
print(df)
```

**Nota adicional:** No sé por qué en tu código utilizas varios `if` ya que por lo que veo las combinaciónes son únicas y deberían ir en `if` `elif`, ya que únicamente una combinación sería válida para cada fila.

El código anterior imprime el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
             Close  Position Buy/Sell
Date                                 
2018-02-06  150.61       1.0      0.0
2018-06-29  160.08       0.0     Sell
2019-07-09  178.17       0.0     Hold
2020-03-16  140.35       1.0      Buy
2020-08-24  189.40       1.0     Hold
2020-12-03  200.60       1.0     Hold
2020-12-15  202.46       0.0     Sell
2021-01-08  209.26       0.0     Hold
2021-01-27  207.54       1.0      Buy
2021-04-16  230.39       1.0     Hold
```

Y puedes seguir procesándolo con `df[df['Buy/Sell'] != 'Hold'].dropna()` o lo que desees.